# Google Analytics Custom Event Tracking Partially Working

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add a custom tracking event for 11 buttons on a website. However, google analytics is only tracking the two buttons on the home page (BtnHome1 and BtnHome2) and not the rest on the other pages. The code is inserted via Google Tag manager and set to trigger for all pages. The tracking code is the following:

```
<script>

document.getElementById("BtnHome1").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnHome1', 'click', '']);
 }
   document.getElementById("BtnHome2").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnHome2', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnMasterPlan").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnMasterPlan', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnUbicacionAmenities").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnUbicacionAmenities', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnDelMarResidents").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnDelMarResidents', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnParaisoDelMar").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnParaisoDelMar', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnSantaAnaDelMar").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnSantaAnaDelMar', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnPorqueInvertir").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnPorqueInvertir', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("Btn4ventajasGolf").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Btn4ventajasGolf', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnEcogolf").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnEcogolf', 'click', '']);
 }
    document.getElementById("BtnConoceArquitectos").onclick = function(){
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'BtnConoceArquitectos', 'click', '']);
 }
 </script>
```

The site is [here](http://www.mardeindias.com/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Is the hit not being fired on the page? Or is it being fired and the data is not showing in your reporting view?

Comment: The hit is being fired but the data is not showing up in analytics, only for the 2 first buttons

Comment: In that case I would check if your view has any filters that would rewrite or exclude those event hits or the pages where those hits would be triggered

Comment: @AndrésSandoval I think It would be difficult to help you without having access to your account (GA/GTM). But I have a question, why don't you use GA event tag in GTM directly ? I would be easy to debug... also it might be the getElementById which is working properly only for the first two events...